# 500 internal server error routing codeigniter 3

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I Know this question is already asked but I've not found how solve my problem.
I use codeigniter 3

This is my .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This links work :

```
- http://domain/cercle/
- http://domain/index.php/cercle/
```

But they don't :

```
- http://domain/jeu/carafe/5
- http://domain/index.php/jeu/carafe/5
```

And my test don't work also:

```
- http://domain/aie
```

My config['route']:

```
$route['cercle/']                                           = 'cercle';
$route['carafe/(:int)']                                     = 'jeu/carafe/$1';
$route['aie']                                               = 'jeu/carafe/5';
```

My config['index_page'] :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

(don't work better if I add 'index.php';)

My config['uri_protocol'] :

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

If I config with `QUERY_STRING`, the browser always display the homepage

My server work with ISPconfig and I try CGI, Fast-CGI, suPHP, mod-Php ^^

Please save me !

EDIT : When I select Fast-CGI I've not a Internal Error but this message : No `input file specified.`  :(

Comment: What does your error logs say?

Comment: I don't know how see that. I think I've not access to the log file or maybe it'snt exist. I edit my post for the new details

Comment: Since you're using rewrite rules, I think you should remove your routes variables and look into using `_remap()` to achieve what you're trying  to do.

Comment: Thank. I have test with _remap() with the help of this link : [link](http://tutorialsplane.com/codeigniter-remap-function/)

Their example work but I've a Internal Server Error when I use my ctrl...

In my Ctrl : 
`public function _remap($method){

 pdebug($method);
 die();
 switch ($method) {
  case 'about' : 
   $this->about_me();// call about_me() function.
  break;
  case 'edu' : 
   $this->education();// call education() function.
  break;
  default :
   $this->index();
  break;
 }

}`

Maybe the problem come from my construct function ?

Comment: Use num instead of int, and show your controller. Maybe it will tell something.

Comment: The problem is solved but I don't know how or why ...
I've delete my .htaccess, replace my routes and remove _remap function.
ISPConfig is now Fast-CGI. 
I have always a 2nd big problem but I think I go to create a new post for that. I continue to check this issue for understand that appends and why it's work now... I'm a little lost.